# Rails build fails in Travis due to undefined method 'encrypted_password=' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, travis-ci

So I have a User model that uses the Devise gem.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: USERS
#
#  u_id                   :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string(255)      default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string(255)      default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string(255)
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0), not null
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string(255)
#  join_date              :datetime
#  organization           :string(255)
#  created_at             :datetime
#  updated_at             :datetime
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  self.table_name = "USERS"
end
```

I also have a Factory girl factory to create the user object for my RSpec tests

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |user|
    user.email 'test@example.com'
    user.password Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  end
end
```

All my tests on my local environment with `rake spec` pass, but when I run the Travis build, it always fails at the RSpec tests with:

```
undefined method `encrypted_password=' for #<User:0x67c24931>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:26:in `(root)'
```

Here is my user_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  it "successfully creates a user" do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    expect(@user.save).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

I've checked via `rails c` that `User.new.respond_to?(:encrypted_password=)` returns true. I'm not sure what could be wrong and I can't find any answers to my problem. So, am I missing something?

Edit:

Forgot to include my .travis.yml

```
language: ruby
rvm:
    - jruby-1.7.15
env:
    - DB=mysql

script:
    - export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
    - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate spec
before_script:
    - mysql -e 'create database test_db'
```

EDIT2:
Adding in Travis log for db migrations

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate spec
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20141031200108 CreateAllTables: migrating ==================================
-- create_table("GROUPS", {:primary_key=>"g_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0130s
-- create_table("TICKET_PRIORITY", {:primary_key=>"tp_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0120s
-- create_table("USERS", {:primary_key=>"u_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0110s
-- create_table("BOARDS", {:primary_key=>"b_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0120s
-- add_index("BOARDS", ["current_sprint_id"], {:name=>"current_sprint_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0370s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_index("BOARDS", ["p_id"], {:name=>"p_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0200s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("COMMENTS", {:primary_key=>"c_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0120s
-- add_index("COMMENTS", ["u_id"], {:name=>"u_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0210s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("GROUP_PERMISSIONS", {:id=>false, :force=>true})
   -> 0.0120s
-- add_index("GROUP_PERMISSIONS", ["g_id"], {:name=>"g_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0190s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("PROJECTS", {:primary_key=>"p_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0150s
-- add_index("PROJECTS", ["owner_id"], {:name=>"owner_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0190s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("SPRINTS", {:primary_key=>"s_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0110s
-- add_index("SPRINTS", ["b_id"], {:name=>"b_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0190s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("TICKET_ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY", {:id=>false, :force=>true})
   -> 0.0140s
-- add_index("TICKET_ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY", ["t_id"], {:name=>"t_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0210s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_index("TICKET_ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY", ["u_id"], {:name=>"u_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0210s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("TICKET_STATUS_HISTORY", {:primary_key=>"tsh_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0130s
-- add_index("TICKET_STATUS_HISTORY", ["t_id"], {:name=>"t_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0180s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("TICKET_TAGS", {:id=>false, :force=>true})
   -> 0.0120s
-- add_index("TICKET_TAGS", ["t_id"], {:name=>"t_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0170s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("TICKETS", {:primary_key=>"t_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0150s
-- add_index("TICKETS", ["b_id"], {:name=>"b_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0180s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_index("TICKETS", ["current_status_id"], {:name=>"current_status_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0180s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_index("TICKETS", ["s_id"], {:name=>"s_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0220s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_index("TICKETS", ["tp_id"], {:name=>"tp_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0220s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("USER_GROUP", {:id=>false, :force=>true})
   -> 0.0160s
-- add_index("USER_GROUP", ["g_id"], {:name=>"g_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0190s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_index("USER_GROUP", ["u_id"], {:name=>"u_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0180s
   -> 0 rows
== 20141031200108 CreateAllTables: migrated (0.5070s) =========================
== 20141031201446 UpdateEnumsInTables: migrating ==============================
-- remove_column(:TICKETS, :type, :string)
   -> 0.0290s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_column(:TICKETS, :type, :integer)
   -> 0.0250s
   -> 0 rows
-- remove_column(:TICKET_ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY, :relationship, :string)
   -> 0.0240s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_column(:TICKET_ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY, :relationship, :integer)
   -> 0.0280s
   -> 0 rows
-- remove_column(:TICKET_STATUS_HISTORY, :new_status, :string)
   -> 0.0250s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_column(:TICKET_STATUS_HISTORY, :new_status, :integer)
   -> 0.0250s
   -> 0 rows
== 20141031201446 UpdateEnumsInTables: migrated (0.1580s) =====================
== 20141106220707 ModifyGroupPermissions: migrating ===========================
-- remove_column(:GROUP_PERMISSIONS, :name)
   -> 0.0230s
   -> 0 rows
-- remove_column(:GROUP_PERMISSIONS, :rank)
   -> 0.0250s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_column(:GROUP_PERMISSIONS, :pm_id, :integer)
   -> 0.0280s
   -> 0 rows
-- create_table("PERMISSIONS", {:primary_key=>"pm_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0110s
== 20141106220707 ModifyGroupPermissions: migrated (0.0880s) ==================
== 20141107011729 DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:users, {:primary_key=>"u_id", :force=>true})
   -> 0.0160s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0350s
   -> 0 rows
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0200s
   -> 0 rows
== 20141107011729 DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.0790s) =======================
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke spec:prepare (first_time)
** Execute spec:prepare
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute spec
```

Edit:

I also tried running `mysql -uroot -e 'use test_db; describe users;'` right before running `rake spec` on travis and it showed the user table had the encrypted_password column. I also ran `cat db/schema.rb` to see if the migrations fully happened, and encrypted_password was also there. Now I'm not sure what could be wrong since the field is in the database.

Comment: probably the issue is with migration test db. show your travis logs

Comment: Added Travis db migration logs

Comment: -- create_table("USERS", {:primary_key=>"u_id", :force=>true})
does this migration include missing column?

Comment: Yes. I even ran a `mysql -e 'use test_db; describe users;'` before running `rake spec` in travis and it showed the column that is being complained about there. So it exists in the test_db right before the tests are ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when I created my tables in MySQL I used capital names for all my table names. For some reason when running it locally, the table names were still uppercase in development mode, but were lowercase for test mode. So, in my user model, I simply changed the `self.table_name = "USERS"` to `self.table_name = "users"` and that fixed my problem.